# What does "The scale is always heavily weighted" mean?

Tags: meaning, proverbs, literature

What does "The scale is always heavily weighted" mean?

> Even at the present day the air is charged with
> prejudice. If any man of standing at the present instant were to enter a
> London newspaper office and say that he had detected a medium in
> fraud, the matter would be seized upon eagerly and broadcast over the
> country; while if the same man proclaimed that he had beyond all
> question satisfied himself that the phenomena were true, it is doubtful
> if he would get a paragraph. **The scale is always heavily weighted**.

*[The History of Spiritualism](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html#chap11)*   By A.C Doyle
<sub>XI.THE RESEARCHES OF SIR WILLIAM CROOKES (1870-1874)</sub>

Comment: If you have an old-style weighing (balance) scale such as [this picture](https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/5-50137_balance-weighing-scales-clipart.png) it should be level when empty. If it is not, it has been **weighted** so that, for example, a merchant can sell you short measure. In regard to the quotation, it means that people's opinion is biassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the news media (newspapers, at that time) are more in favour of (maybe even prejudicial towards)  refuting the existence of the phenomena rather than confirming their existence.